# Can't load my angular component using routing by id

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, routes

I'm working on my personal portfolio and I can't visualize my edit-experience component even if the url changes dinamically. I've checked my project api with postman and there is no problem from the backend. If you could help me, I'd be so grateful. :)

I checked every file of the component but I can't solve the problem. The objective is to change from the experience component to the edit mode(edit-experience-component) routing using "id".
When I click "EDITAR" button, the url changes but the page turns completely white. In the other hand, there is no problem with the component that creates the experiences or with the button that deletes the experience.

*This is the app-routing-module.ts path*

{path: 'editexp/:id', component: EditExperienceComponent}

*This is the experience form that shoud be displayed*

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="expLab">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <form (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()" novalidate #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nombreE">Nombre de la empresa</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreE" name="nombreE" [(ngModel)]="expLab.nombreE" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="descripcionE">Descripcion de la tarea</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcionE" name="descripcionE" [(ngModel)]="expLab.descripcionE" required>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
          Actualizar
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*This is the TS class of the edit-component*

```
import { SExperienciaService } from './../../services/s-experiencia.service';
import { Experiencia } from 'src/app/model/experiencia';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-experience',
  templateUrl: './edit-experience.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-experience.component.css']
})
export class EditExperienceComponent implements OnInit {
  expLab: Experiencia  = null;

  constructor(
    private sExperiencia: SExperienciaService,
    private activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute,
    private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.activatedRouter.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.sExperiencia.detail(id).subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.expLab = data[0];
    }, err =>{
      alert("Error al modificar experiencia");
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
    )
  }

  onUpdate(): void{
    const id = this.activatedRouter.snapshot.params["id"];
      this.sExperiencia.update(id, this.expLab).subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      }, err =>{
        alert("Error al modificar experiencia");
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

*This is the button from the main experience-component that redirects to editexp/:id ...(it works correctly) and it redirects  to 'http://localhost:4200/editexp/9'*

```
<td *ngIf="isLogged">
                  <button class="btn btn-succes" routerLink="editexp/{{experiencia.id}}">
                  <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>EDITAR</button></td>
```

The other problem, that may be related is that in NetBeans, when I start the project, is that the next file is sending me an error, until I log in.

*This is the error that sends me inside netbeans*

**c.p.euka.Security.JWT.JwtEntryPoint      : FallÃ³ el metodo commence**

```
package com.portfolio.euka.Security.JWT;


import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JwtEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Falló el metodo commence");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to provide more debugging details like errors on your console, response object etc.

Comment: The problem is that on my console there is no visible error, just sends me "alert("Error al modificar experiencia");" from the TS of the edit-component and redirects me or just keeps the screen white until I click on the alert.

Comment: There should of been error but because you are navigating away when you're getting the error you don't see it. Remove the navigate and you'll see the error. The problem obviously within your API call.

Comment: I removed de navigate from the edit-experience component TS so I don't get redirected, but as before I get the table info that i'm supposed to edit, but the page keeps white and the edit component doesn't show, even if the url successfully changes to 'http://localhost:4200/editexp/9'